# SonarQube doesn't increase test coverage as I write more and more tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, intellij-idea, sonarqube

I've been facing a really weird problem with a project and the use of SonarQube.

As you can see in the image below, my test coverage is 9.5% of my overall code which is pretty low regarding of the quantity of code I've been writing and will be in the future.

[image]

When I first tried to write tests, they were not detected, because I forgot a plugin inside my pom.xml, which I added and is the following

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
 <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>0.8.8</version>
 <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

After that, I got this window on SonarQube.

[image]

Nice ! My test are detected and I went to 13.2% on new code and 9.5% overall !
But that's where the real problem started, as I wrote more test and be pushing them to SonarQube, nothing more was shown. The percentage didn't increased, and the line that I thought the tests covered were not.
And the weirdest part is that the test code was on SonarQube ! It was pushed to Sonar but not detected as test code or whatever it should be !

So, I tried to watch as many videos as I could but nothing seems to really work and I just had the feeling that I lost time. I've been trying to code simple test classes on my simplest classes, for example :
Here is my class : Categorie.java

```
package com.back.projetbdi_groupe1.Entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Categorie {
    @Id
    private String idCategorie;

    private String libCateg;

    public String getIdCategorie() {
        return idCategorie;
    }

    public void setIdCategorie(String idCategorie) {
        this.idCategorie = idCategorie;
    }

    public String getLibCateg() {
        return libCateg;
    }

    public void setLibCateg(String libCateg) {
        this.libCateg = libCateg;
    }
}
```

And my test class : CategorieTest.java

```
package com.back.projetbdi_groupe1.entities;

import com.back.projetbdi_groupe1.Entities.Categorie;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class CategorieTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetIdCategorie(){
        Categorie categorie = new Categorie();
        categorie.setIdCategorie("1");
        assertEquals("1",categorie.getIdCategorie());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetLibCateg(){
        Categorie categorie = new Categorie();
        categorie.setLibCateg("categ");
        assertEquals("categ",categorie.getLibCateg());
    }
}
```

You can see it in sonar :
[image]

But :
[image]
You can see that nothing is covered.
So, I wanted to know if I'm not testing the right way, or is it a SonarQube bug ? Or my pom.xml is incomplete ? I will put what I found useful about the pom.xml below.
Oh, and to " push " to SonarQube the code, I'm using the following command : mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=MyFabulousAndLongToken

Rest of the pom.xml :

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jettyVersion>9.4.3.v20170317</jettyVersion>
        <jettyServletVersion>9.4.3.v20170317</jettyServletVersion>
        <sonar.host.url>http://im2ag-sonar.u-ga.fr:9000/</sonar.host.url>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to resolve my own problem I did nothing but testing my code "less wrongly" if I could say.

That's what the previous example of testing looks like now !

```html
package com.back.projetbdi_groupe1.Entities;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class CategorieTest {
    /**
     * Methods under test:
     *
     * <ul>
     *   <li>default or parameterless constructor of {@link Categorie}
     *   <li>{@link Categorie#setIdCategorie(String)}
     *   <li>{@link Categorie#setLibCateg(String)}
     *   <li>{@link Categorie#getIdCategorie()}
     *   <li>{@link Categorie#getLibCateg()}
     * </ul>
     */
    static Categorie actualCategorie;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        actualCategorie = new Categorie();
        actualCategorie.setIdCategorie("1");
        actualCategorie.setLibCateg("Lib Categ");
    }

    @Test
    void testGetIdCategorie() {
        assertEquals("1", actualCategorie.getIdCategorie());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetLibCateg() {
        assertEquals("Lib Categ", actualCategorie.getLibCateg());
    }
}
```

And in Sonar :
[image]

Everything is green, im H A P P Y.

Comment: What changes do you think made the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer, just some things that should be checked.

It's a little odd to use the "clean" goal on the same mvn command line you run "sonar:sonar", but it's possible that can work.  Inspect the output from this command and verify that it's running all of your unit tests.

When Jacoco and Surefire are properly integrated, it should generate an html page you can visit to inspect the Jacoco results.  It might be in "target/jacoco_report".  If that is there (it's possible it might be in a different subdirectory), then view that in your browser and see if there are tests missing from that report.  SonarQube only integrates the jacoco data that is produced.

In the SonarQube results, you can also see the list of unit tests that are executed.  See if "CategorieTest" is in that list.

Comment: Jacoco was showing a great test report but my test were " not good enough " for Sonar, I don't really know why but when I asked one of my professor to help me with my tests, he wrote a simple one which made the percentage increase. So I just kept going using tutorials and that was it, nothing was wrong with my project, only the way I was testing it !

Comment: The problem is somehow related to JUnit dependencies / versions - you have both JUnit 5 (..the jupiter deps...) and JUnit 4 ( junit / junit 4.13) in your pom and the (not coveraged) code in question is JUnit4 style. Are you really sure that the build alone picked up the tests and Jacoco coveraged them? Not from IDE such as Eclipse or IDEA but from Maven build?

Comment: If you are writing new code I would suggest not to mix JUnit 4 and 5. I would suggest to stick to JUnit 5 dependencies in pom and to JUnit 5 code style, i.e. remove the junit 4x from pom and code the JUnit 5 style.

Comment: It is possible to have both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests (we have that right now), but I know it can be challenging to ensure that Surefire gets both of them. It's possible that you've ended up with the configuration that results in the JUnit 4 tests not being executed. If the new tests your professor wrote were using JUnit 5, that could explain why those worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Junit 5.0 you should replace **org.junit.Test** on to
**org.junit.jupiter.api.Test**